# How to write Laravel eloquent query inside model function?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, model, controller

Actually I don't know how to retrieve data from db using function and query inside model .Please help me what should i add inside model function.

Here is controller

```
public function checkAdmin(Request $request){
        $data  = array();
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['password'] = $request->password;
        $found = AdminModel::checkAdmin($data);
        if($found == TRUE){
            echo "found";
        }
        else{
            echo "sorry";
        }
    }
```

Here is the Model Function

```
public static function checkAdmin($data){
        $found = $this->where('email',$data['email'])->where('password',$data['password'])->first();
        return $found;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the `checkAdmin` function? Are you trying to validate a login? If yes, Laravel does this for you out of the box with the `Auth::attempt` method:

```
$credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    // Authentication passed...
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication#authenticating-users

However to answer your question, you could do so like this:

```
$userFound = AdminModel::where(['email' => $request->email, 'password] => $request->password)->count();

if($userFound){
    echo "found";
}
else{
    echo "sorry";
}
```